# Count which combination of items are bought most frequently

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What is an efficient method of doing this?

I have a column with name of buyer and a column with item names. Each item the person bought is on a new row

For example:

```
Person 1    Item 1
Person 1    Item 2
Person 1    Item 5
Person 1    Item 7
Person 2    Item 1
Person 2    Item 2
Person 2    Item 11
Person 2    Item 15
Person 2    Item 20
Person 2    Item 21
Person 2    Item 17
Person 3    Item 1
Person 3    Item 2
Person 3    Item 6
Person 3    Item 11
Person 3    Item 15
Person 4    Item 1
Person 4    Item 2
Person 4    Item 5
Person 4    Item 7
```

There are about 1000000 rows in total and each person has an average of 30 items.

I want to count how often two specific items are bought by a person. 
I am picturing it something like this

```
      Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6
Item1 xxxxx    0%   0%    5%    10%  90%
Item2   
Item3
Item4   
Item5   
Item6
```

I have tried using pivot table putting item on row labels and person on column labels then counting items. Then I can use a formula lookup and multiply the results from the pivot table but this is doesn't work with such a large file. Is there a more efficient method?

I am open to all kinds of solutions.

Comment: 1M row is too much for `Countif` I guess, use `PivotTable` instead.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am looking into right now. I don't know how to configure pivottable to see how commonly a person buys two specific items. I am using excel 2010 so I can't use powerpivot.

Comment: With one million rows I would consider moving to Access or SQL/SQLExpress,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper 'table' to do this. First create a table of purchases by person. The formula in this table is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$20=E$2),--($B$1:$B$20=$D3))
```

Which gives a 1/0 result if a person ever bought that item. Example:

[image]

Then create the grid of products like in your post and enter this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($E3:$H3,INDEX($E$3:$H$12,MATCH(K$2,$D$3:$D$12,0),0))
```

Which multiples instances of purchase of Item X and Item Y. Example:[image]

Comment: How would this work if I had hundreds of thousands of rows?

Comment: There is only about 100 items but a lot more people

Comment: is it possible to get that result using a pivot table instead (or two pivot tables)?

Comment: If you got 1m rows use a database.

Comment: Interesting answer. I did not understand, why you wrote --(...), but I tried it out. Thats your way to make a number from a boolean? I tried <-(), -()>, it worked in the same way (cause "-" * "-" gives "+") and <1*(), 1*()> works too. Nice Answer, I learned something new.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue because I have too many rows but I marked it as correct since it does what I asked for. I would gladly accept help with optimizing it (using vba or something)

Comment: for my opinion this IS the answer. Maybe your data is to big for using it.

Comment: Yeah I tried this method and it takes forever to load and excel  stops responding for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand you, but you are not interested in the person, who buys but in the items, bought by the same person? I do not think you can do this in one step only using formulas (of course in vba you can do it easier).

To do it w/o vba you could:

1. List item
2. Sort by Person and Item
3. Build an accumulating string with all (different) items bought by one person
   (untested: something like IF(A1=A2;B1;"")&B2
4. Ignore all strings but the last of a person (something like IF(A2=A3;"";B2)

After this you have something like

```
P   I   Items_a All_Items
1   A   A   
1   B   AB  
1   E   ABE 
1   G   ABEG    ABEG
2   A   A   
2   B   AB  
2   K   ABK 
2   O   ABKO    
2   Q   ABKOQ   
2   T   ABKOQT  
2   U   ABKOQTU ABKOQTU
3   A   A   
3   B   AB  
3   F   ABF 
3   K   ABFK    
3   O   ABFKO   ABFKO
4   A   A   
4   B   AB  
4   E   ABE 
4   G   ABEG    ABEG
```

In the next step you could copy all combinations to a new table, and build all combinations (ascending, cause items were sorted) in a column and mark as 1 if condition matches

To explain it easier the items are named A, B, ... (corresponding to Item 1, Item 2 ... in your example)
The formula is something like 
=IF(IS_ERROR(FIND(PART(B$1;1;1);$A2));0;1)*IF(IS_ERROR(FIND(PART(B$1;2;1);$A2));0;1)

And your case it would be the following possible combinations

AB  AE  AF  AG  AK  AO  AQ  AT  AU  BE  BF  BG  BK  BO  BQ  BT  BU  EF  EG  EK  EO  EQ  ET  EU  FG  FK  FO  FQ  FT  FU  GK  GO  GQ  GT  GU  KO  KQ  KT  KU  OQ  OT  OU  QT  QU  TU

But in this example 66% exist, So I only Show the beginning of the table:

```
XXXXX   AB  AE  AF  AG  AK  AO  AQ  AT  AU  BE  BF
ABEG    1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
ABEG    1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
ABFKO   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
ABKOQTU 1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
SUM ALL 4   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   1
```

And now you can count, whatever you want.

A simple WVERWEIS function would help to get this:

```
    A   B   E   F   G   K   O   Q   T   U
A   0   4   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1
B   0   0   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1
E   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
F   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
K   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   1   1
O   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
Q   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
T   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
U   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But for my opinion you can handle that for maybe 10 Items (the Help- Cols would be n*(n-1)/2, 10 Items --> 45 Columns (cause AA, BB, ... are not evaluated)

In all other cases you should try to program that.

Comment: Yeah doing this programmatically is probably a good idea. I have never done anything in vba but do know a bit of c# if that helps. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction on where to find info and how this would be done in vba?

Comment: "(of course in vba you can do it easier)." What step would be easier in vba?

Comment: You wouldn't have to sort your data manually, you could automatically find all listed items, you could eliminate not existing combinations and so on. To be understood correctly: It is work to do it in vba, but you can eliminate manual work (what f.e. produces errors and costs lot of time, if the table is that big as you say)