# Count of most frequent combinations sold

Tags: google-sheets

I'm referencing this older question, but I am having trouble updating the formula for my needs as my column and rows are switched and my data set has too many rows to transpose to make his formula work properly (google sheets or numbers)

[Count which combination of items are bought most frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516727/count-which-combination-of-items-are-bought-most-frequently)

The formula in this picture is not quite working for me.

[image: table image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT($E3:$H3,INDEX($E$3:$H$12,MATCH(K$2,$D$3:$D$12,0),0))
```

How would I get that to work if my data was the same, but column and rows were switched?  To be more specific, I have items as the header, and order numbers as rows (I have > 15k rows).

What I'm trying to do is take a large set of order data and find which combinations of products people are ordering most often.  My initial search led me to creating the matrix as posted above.  That would totally work for output, I'm just not able to get a formula to work using the other posts I've read.

Maybe a better example of what output may look like?[image]

Comment: To clarify - my data in the helper table above (left) is switched.  My goal is for the output table on the right to work with the transposed data on the left.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: My data sheet looks like the picture above, just with the row/column labels switched.   I have 15k+ rows, each as an order, with Items listed up top.

My desired output would look exactly like the table on the right in the initial post.  The cells will hopefully be a count of the number of times a specific product is sold with another product in an order.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E$3:E$100,INDEX($3:$100,0,MATCH($Q2,$2:$2,0)))
```

It would work like this:

[image]

**Important:** For this solution to work you'd need to change the range that contains the data. For example, the data reaches row 1500:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E$3:E$1500,INDEX($3:$1500,0,MATCH($Q2,$2:$2,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It looks like it calculates the first cell correctly but doesn't want to expand to others.

Comment: That's odd, it works fine for me, could you share an example of the output that you need based on your new structure?

Comment: In your output table above, does it also have headers of the same items? My ideal state would be a matrix with the same list of items as row and column headers.  The data int he matrix would be the sum of all of the times those two items were sold together in the same order (whichever items from the column and row headers the cell references)